# Cannot push element to the head of the linked list

Tags: c, linked-list, dynamic-memory-allocation, doubly-linked-list, function-definition

I'm trying to implement linked list in C and I've got a problem with wrong output. The first element seems not to be pushed in the head of the list.

I expect the below output in the program:

```
1
1
```

Actual output:

```
0
0
```

Have you ideas what's wrong with the code? Thanks

Problematic code:

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "linked_list.h"

int main(void) {
    struct ll_node *node = ll_new();
    ll_push_front(node, 1);
    printf("%d\n", ll_size(node)); // should print 1, actual output: 0
    printf("%d\n", ll_pop_back(node)); // should print 1, actual output: 0
    ll_destroy(node);
    return 0;
}
```

linked_list.h

```
#ifndef LINKED_LIST_H
#define LINKED_LIST_H
#include <stdbool.h>

struct ll_node {
    int data;
    struct ll_node *prev;
    struct ll_node *next;
};

struct ll_node *ll_new();
void ll_destroy(struct ll_node *node);
void ll_push_back(struct ll_node *node, int data);
void ll_push_front(struct ll_node *node, int data);
int ll_pop_back(struct ll_node *node);
int ll_pop_front(struct ll_node *node);
int ll_delete_at(struct ll_node *node, int index);
bool ll_contains(struct ll_node *node, int data);
int ll_find(struct ll_node *node, int data);
int ll_size(struct ll_node *node);

#endif //LINKED_LIST_H
```

linked_list.c

```
#include "linked_list.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct ll_node *ll_new() {
    struct ll_node* node = (struct ll_node *) malloc(sizeof(struct ll_node *));
    if (!node) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: cannot allocate struct ll_node *node at ll_new");
        exit(1);
    }
    node->prev = NULL;
    node->next = NULL;
    return node;
}

void ll_destroy(struct ll_node *node) {
    while (node->next != NULL) {
        struct ll_node *elem = node;
        node = node->next;
        free(elem);
    }
}

void ll_push_back(struct ll_node *node, int data) {
    while (node->next != NULL) {
        node = node->next;
    }
    struct ll_node *current = (struct ll_node *) malloc(sizeof(struct node *));
    current->data = data;
    current->next = NULL;
    current->prev = node;
    node->next = current;
}

void ll_push_front(struct ll_node *node, int data) {
    struct ll_node *current = (struct ll_node *) malloc(sizeof(struct node *));
    current->data = data;
    current->next = node;
    current->prev = NULL;
    node->prev = current;
}

int ll_pop_back(struct ll_node *node) {
    struct ll_node *current = node;
    while (current->next != NULL) {
        current = current->next;
    }
    int old_data = current->data;
    free(current);
    return old_data;
}

int ll_pop_front(struct ll_node *node) {
    // TODO: implement this
}

int ll_delete_at(struct ll_node *node, int index) {
    // TODO: implement this
}

bool ll_contains(struct ll_node *node, int data) {
    while (node->next != NULL) {
        if (node->data != data) {
            return false;
        }
        node = node->next;
    }
    return true;
}

int ll_find(struct ll_node *node, int data) {
    // TODO: implement this
}

int ll_size(struct ll_node *node) {
    int size = 0;
    while (node->next != NULL) {
        ++size;
        node = node->next;
    }
    return size;
}
```

Comment: When you do `ll_push_front(node, 1);`, do you expect that the value of `node` will change? Why? The purpose is to put a node *in front of* `node`, right? As in, the new node will point to `node`, not the other way around, right? Therefore, in your own words, how is the code supposed to find the new node that was just added, if it only has the `node` pointer?

Comment: In your own words, what logical steps do you think should be involved in the process of adding the new node - in English? When you push something to the front of the list, does the list now still have the same element at the front? Therefore, if you are keeping track of the list by holding a pointer to the first element, should that pointer change? What techniques could you use, to make that happen?

Comment: Also, consider: the *purpose of* `ll_new` is to create new nodes, right? In some other functions that you have, do you need to create new nodes? Do you use `ll_new` there? Why not?

Answer (score 0):

#### When you push something on to the front of a list, don't you need to return a pointer to the new list?

Surely this code should be changed to `return` a pointer to `current`.

```
void ll_push_front(struct ll_node *node, int data) {
    struct ll_node *current = (struct ll_node *) malloc(sizeof(struct node *));
    current->data = data;
    current->next = node;
    current->prev = NULL;
    node->prev = current;
}
```

Then in the calling function, you should be reading that result and storing it as the new list, I think?

Comment: A similar issue exists when popping.

Comment: Yes: Because we want this list to be editable at both ends, we need to not be fixated on a particular object as the "start" of it. Whenever calling a push or pop on the _front_ (or _start_) of the list, we need to return a pointer to the new start.

Comment: You didn't allocate memory for the `struct` and are referencing illegal memory.

Comment: And this is not the only option. The traditional method is to a pass a pointer to the caller's memory.

Answer (score 0):

1. `struct ll_node *node = ll_new();` allocates a new node (let's call it root), obviously, but then you push a new node into front (let's call it node(1):

```
root->next = NULL
root->prev = node(1)
node(1)->next = root
node(1)->prev = NULL
```

In `main()` `node *` still points to root, and indeed, it's `next` pointer is NULL, so `ll_size()` returns 0.  You probably want to return the new root node and do this in `main()` or pass in the node as `struct ll_node **` so you can update it.

```
node = ll_push_front(node, 1);
```

2. Prefer to use the variable rather than type for allocations, and don't cast the `void *` pointer:

```
 struct ll_node *current = malloc(sizeof *current);
```

This also fixes the defect of allocating size of a pointer but you require size of the object.

3. You have a `ll_new()` function but but `ll_push_front()` and `ll_push_back()` implements the same thing again.  You should refactor the latter two to use `ll_new()`.
4. It's not necessarily wrong just confusing that you use `struct ll_node` to both represent a node of your linked list, and the entire linked list.  The root node, for instance, has uninitialized `data`.
5. You will need to make similar changes to `ll_pop_back()`, and you need to update all the relevant pointers.
6. What should `ll_pop_back()` do if the list is empty?
7. `ll_destroy()` doesn't free the current node.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

struct ll_node {
    int data;
    struct ll_node *prev;
    struct ll_node *next;
};

struct ll_node *ll_new() {
    struct ll_node* node = malloc(sizeof *node);
    if (!node) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: cannot allocate struct ll_node *node at ll_new");
        exit(1);
    }
    return node;
}

void ll_push_front(struct ll_node **root, int data) {
    if(!root) {
        printf("root must be non-NULL");
        exit(1);
    }
    struct ll_node *current = ll_new();
    current->data = data;
    current->prev = NULL;
    current->next = *root;
    if(*root)
    
    (*root)->prev = current;
    *root = current;
}

int ll_pop_back(struct ll_node **root) {
    if(!root) {
        printf("root must be non-NULL");
        exit(1);
    }
    if(!*root) {
        printf("*root must be non-NULL");
        exit(1);
    }
    struct ll_node *current = *root;
    while (current->next != NULL) {
        current = current->next;
    }
    int data = current->data;
    if(current->prev)
        current->prev->next = NULL;
    else
        *root = NULL;
    free(current);
    return data;
}

int ll_size(struct ll_node *node) {
    size_t n = 0;
    for(; node; node = node->next, n++);
    return n;
}

void ll_destroy(struct ll_node *root) {
    while(root) {
        struct ll_node *tmp = root->next;
        free(root);
        root = tmp;
    }
}

int main(void) {
    struct ll_node *root = NULL;
    ll_push_front(&root, 'a');
    ll_push_front(&root, 'b');
    printf("%d\n", ll_size(root));
    printf("%c\n", ll_pop_back(&root));
    printf("%d\n", ll_size(root));
    printf("%c\n", ll_pop_back(&root));
    printf("%d\n", ll_size(root));
    ll_destroy(root);
}
```

and the resulting output:

```
2
a
1
b
0
```

Answer (score 0):

For starters within the function `ll_new` there is incorrectly allocated memory for a node of the list.

```
struct ll_node* node = (struct ll_node *) malloc(sizeof(struct ll_node *));
```

Instead you need to write either

```
struct ll_node* node = (struct ll_node *) malloc(sizeof(struct ll_node ));
```

or

```
struct ll_node* node = (struct ll_node *) malloc(sizeof( *node ));
```

The function does not make a great sense because it does not initialize the data member `data` of the created node.

The same problem with allocation memory exists also in the function `ll_push_front`

```
struct ll_node *current = (struct ll_node *) malloc(sizeof(struct node *));
```

Again you need to write either

```
struct ll_node *current = (struct ll_node *) malloc(sizeof(struct node ));
```

or

```
struct ll_node *current = (struct ll_node *) malloc(sizeof( *current ));
```

Actually everywhere in the code you are using incorrect expressions in calls of `malloc`.

Also the function does not change the pointer to the head node of the list.

It only sets its data member `prev` to the newly created node

As a result the function `ll_size` will always return `0` because the data member `next` of the node pointed to by the pointer `node` declared in main is equal to `NULL`

```
int ll_size(struct ll_node *node) {
    int size = 0;
    while (node->next != NULL) {
        ++size;
        node = node->next;
    }
    return size;
}
```

The function `ll_push_back` can invoke undefine behavior if a null pointer is passed to the function due to this while loop within the function

```
while (node->next != NULL) {
    node = node->next;
}
```

The function `ll_pop_back` again does not check whether a null pointer is passed

```
while (current->next != NULL) {
    current = current->next;
}
```

Also if the list contains only one node then the function does not change the passed pointer. The node will be deleted by the pointer that points to the deleted node will stay unchanged.

Or the function `ll_destroy` does not free all the allocated memory

```
void ll_destroy(struct ll_node *node) {
    while (node->next != NULL) {
        struct ll_node *elem = node;
        node = node->next;
        free(elem);
    }
}
```

leaving the last node in the list undeleted that results in a memory leak due to the condition in the while loop

```
    while (node->next != NULL) {
```

Your code contains many errors. You need to rewrite it. Start from this declaration in main

```
struct ll_node *head = NULL;
```

and try to write at first the function `ll_push_front` that adds one node to the empty list.

The list shall not have a dummy node.

Pay attention to that it would be better to declare one more structure like for example

```
struct linked_list {
    size_t size;
    struct ll_node *head;
    struct ll_node *tail;
};
```

that will indeed specify the double-lonked list.

In this case there will be much efficient to add new nodes to the tail of the list or to determine the size of the list.

You could define a list in `main` like

```
struct linked_list list = { .size = 0, .head = NULL, .tail = NULL };
```

And a function that adds a node to the beginning of the list could look like

```
int ll_push_front( struct linked_list *list, int data );
```

The function can be defined the following way

```
int ll_push_front( struct linked_list *list, int data )
{
    struct ll_node *new_node = malloc( sizeof( *new_node ) );
    int success = new_node != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        new_node_>data = data;
        new_node->next = list->head;
        new_node->prev = NULL; 

        if ( list->head != NULL )
        {
            list->head->prev = new_node;
        }
        else
        {
            list->tail = new_node;
        }

        list->head = new_node;
        ++list->size;
    }

    return success;
}
```

And the function is called in main like for example

```
ll_push_front( &list, 1 );
```

or

```
if ( !ll_push_front( &list, 1 ) )
{
    puts( "Error: not enough memory!" );
}
```

In turn the function `ll_push_back` can look the following way

```
int ll_push_back( struct linked_list *list, int data )
{
    struct ll_node *new_node = malloc( sizeof( *new_node ) );
    int success = new_node != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        new_node_>data = data;
        new_node->next = NULL;
        new_node->prev = list->tail; 

        if ( list->tail != NULL )
        {
            list->tail->next = new_node;
        }
        else
        {
            list->head = new_node;
        }

        list->tail = new_node;
        ++list->size;
    }

    return success;
}
```

To get the size of the list you can write for example

```
size_t ll_size( const struct linked_list *list )
{
    return list->size;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**`sizeof (struct node *)` != `sizeof (struct node)`:**

```
struct ll_node *current = (struct ll_node *) malloc(sizeof(struct node *));
```

only allocates memory for the pointer, which will likely be 8 bytes on a 64-bit machine or 4 bytes on a 32-bit machine.

Change it to:

```
struct ll_node *current = malloc (sizeof *current);
```

Note that the cast is redundant and may hide a bug. There's an implicit conversion to and from a `void *`.

One advice I see most often on codereview.com is to allocate based on the size of what an object points to rather than the object type itself. This eases maintainability.

The function is also discarding the return value of `malloc()`. `malloc()` returns `NULL` to indicate failure. I'd suggest returning a `bool` type for `ll_push_front()`, `true` would indicate success, and `false` can indicate a memory allocation failure.

---

**Changes to local parameters are never reflected back in the caller's memory:**

> The first element seems not to be pushed in the head of the list.

Your push function is very close to being correct. Remember that C has pass-by-value semantics and pointers are not exempt to that rule. As is, your push function only changes its local copy of `head`. This change will not be reflected back in the `main()` function. We need the push function to be able to change the caller's memory. The traditional method to allow a function to change it's caller memory is to pass a pointer to the caller's memory instead of a copy.

So instead of:

```
struct node *head = /* some value */;
push_node (head, /* some value */);
```

We pass a pointer to the head pointer, so the changes made to the head pointer in the push function are reflected back in `main()`.

```
push_node (&head, /* some value */);
```

And dereference the pointer in the push function to access the caller's memory.

There are other issues in your code. I'd suggest implementing a singly linked list before moving on to this.